# Kelvin function KelvinBer[n,z] in Python

Tags: python, bessel-functions

In Mathematica there is the Kelvin function KelvinBer[n,z]. I would need something equivalent in Python with n=0 and n=1.

There is scipy.special.ber(x), but as I understand it and played around, it comes with n=0. Is there an already defined KelvinBer with n=1 available?

I could implement it numerically but if someone knows a quicker way I would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Mpmath**](http://mpmath.org/) has a [`ber()` function](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/bessel.html#ber) that takes an `n` argument.

[image]